# How can i bypass or lower the GestureDetector scroll threshold?

Tags: android, gesture

I have a GestureDetector and i am feeding it MotionEvents and i heavily rely on its return value.

Now when the amount of scroll was too low, there is the following line in the source (android.view.GestureDetector line 578):

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
// several checks that all not apply
else if ((Math.abs(scrollX) >= 1) || (Math.abs(scrollY) >= 1)) {

}
```

but the last else if will not apply if the scroll limit is too low. Imagine a finger scrolling really slow, stopping for a second, continuing to scroll. When the finger stops the detector returns me a FALSE which means i give the event to the next layer etc and this should not happen because it still is a scroll.

If i extend the detector and override the entire method, i had to copy paste everything except that line and enter a 0 there.

Can anyone come up with a more simple solution how my scroll is not interrupted ?

Answer (score 0):

What about listening to ACTION_UP event manually and then giving the event to "next layer" only if gesture listener return false AND you realized user lifted his finger?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // ACTION_UP means user lifted all his fingers
    boolean actionUp = (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
    boolean result = mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    if (!result && actionUp) {
        // Scrolling really finished, do something
    }
}
```